# Minimal .htaccess code for a set of redirection rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to achieve the following behavior with the least number of rules:

1. Enforce HTTPS
2. Redirect www to non-www
3. Remove .php and .html extensions from all URLs
4. Redirect *example.com/index.php* and *example.com/index* to *example.com*
5. Redirect *example.com/static/*.html* to *example.com/**
6. Remove trailing slashes

Right now I use the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

which don't include a rule for the static directory as I don't have introduced it yet. I plan to do it for caching reasons now.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What the title says. If the same results can be achieved with less rules.

Comment: I doubt you can shorten this... But even if that were possible - why? Less rules does _not_ necessarily mean things are more effective. And certainly things are harder to maintain.

Comment: I see an issue with your implementation though: as I see it a request to `http://example.com/some/path` would _not_ get redirected to https, right?

Comment: Everything redirects to https. If my implementation has a mistake then another setting of the server makes the redirection.
If the server has to process less conditions and make less rewrites why things wouldn't be more effective?

Comment: SO you did not post all rewriting rules implemented on your http server? And then ask to optimize them? Hmmmm ... And no, fewer lines not necessarily lead to a more efficient processing. This also depends on the complexity of rules, so for example the complexity of the regular expression. But even _if_ you find a way to gain one or two lines - you really should weight that against raising complexity, thus readability and maintainability. In the long run all that counts is effort you invest, not one or two milliseconds you gain.

Comment: That's all the rewriting related rules I have. Probably something else forces the HTTPS protocol if not my rules.

Comment: Hm, I am always a bit skeptical when magic is assumed ;-) But whatever, if things work that is even better! YeeHaw!

Comment: You certainly could simplify this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]` to that `RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` ...

Comment: And I wonder if it really is worth the extra external redirection (which indeed is expensive) just to remove a trailing slash. Can't you accept and internally rewrite that instead? Though that would leave you with two URLs pointing to the same resource.

Comment: Well, I'm using Cloudflare. I checked it just right now and it's Cloudflare that enforces HTTPS along with HSTS.
From a SEO point of view I think a 301 redirection is way better than having 2 different URLs per page.
How do you think the redirection rule for the static folder should be implemented? (That's No.5 in my list with the requirements). It's also a .html removal rule, so can it get combined with it?

Comment: If you want to redirect that, which is perfectly fine, then I do not see a way to optimize that.